# In "Our Lady of the Tall Trees," who is the Lady, and what is the song trying to say about her?

Tags: cahalen-morrison

*I've decided to ask this question here, in light of the consensus that [songs seem to be on-topic](https://literature.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67/are-songs-and-poems-on-topic). I've tried to keep it to lyrics because there's been some debate about whether the music of a song is on topic or just the words.*

---

Cahalen Morrison and Eli West released an album called "Our Lady of the Tall Trees." The [titular song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wYQlhLEJ5jc) ([lyrics](http://www.songlyrics.com/cahalen-morrison-eli-west/our-lady-of-the-tall-trees-lyrics/)), however, contains a somewhat unclear purpose. I'm having trouble determining if the song is intended to just be as carefree and jovial as it sounds, or if there's some deeper meaning that I'm missing.

This starts with a pretty simple question: *who*, exactly, is the Lady of the Tall Trees? The song doesn't really seem to want to go into any level of detail. All it has to say about this topic is...:

> ...Our lady of a lot
>   Said our lady of this and that
>   And other things that we forgot
>
> ...Our lady of the not
>   Wraps herself in rice and greens
>   And other fancy things she bought

This makes the song somewhat difficult to understand, particularly when it comes to any point that the song might be trying to make surrounding who she is and what she's doing. On the other hand, I could be trying to read a song that just seems to be quietly jovial, and nothing more.

How should I be understanding who the Lady is, and what does it mean to the song?

Comment: I wouldn't normally ask, but given that this is beta, and it's about a topic that's currently under discussion, could the close/downvoter please add some explanation as to why they did so?

Comment: I've upvoted but I'm distinctly worried that the site will descend into "***what do these lyrics mean:SE***".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The song appears to allude to [Our Lady of Guadalupe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Our_Lady_of_Guadalupe), a [religious shrine and icon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basilica_of_Our_Lady_of_Guadalupe) associated with **the Virgin Mary.** The lady in the picture is depicted as wearing a green cloak ruffled around her arms.

> she wears her sleeves all up on her arms.

and

> wraps herself in rice and greens and other fancy things she bought.

Her pose (head bowed, in prayer) is one that will be familiar to any Catholic about to eat their dinner.

> Said our lady of the tall trees
>   Supper's served

---

This is backed up by the [album cover](https://fiddlefreak.com/2012/06/12/preorder-our-lady-of-the-tall-trees/) (by Mike Costello) which distinctly resembles the main icon in the shrine and for which it is primarily known.

[image: An image of two pieces of art, which appear to picture Our Lady of The Tall Trees]